# Probability mass function (piecewise function)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Cant post image due to reputation, posted in comments

Here is a probability mass function and probabilities computed (from a past test). I am confused on the notation of $F(x-)$ - I am assuming it means like a limit and approaching from one side. Why is this being used, especially in questions b, c, and e? For example with e, Why is $P(X=1)$ not just $F(1)$?

Comment: Link didnt show up, whoops: http://imgur.com/yKgacFd

Comment: The distribution function $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, not the probability mass function or the probability density function. It is defined by $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x)$.

Comment: So what is the meaning of approaching from the left side? I realize I just made a pretty big error by confusing the two, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The distribution function $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, not the probability mass function or the probability density function. It is defined by $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x)$.

I am assuming $F(x-)$ denotes $\lim_{t \nearrow x} F(t)$, where the limit is for $t$ approaching $x$ from below. You may want to convince yourself that $F(x-) = \mathbb{P}(X<x)$ (in contrast with $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x)$).

Comment: Your logic makes sense but it does not agree with the answer to question part b?

Comment: @user3874530 $F(1)-F(\frac{1}{2}-)=P(X \le 1) - P(X < 1/2) = P(1/2 \le X \le 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $F(x-)$ does mean approaching a limit $x$ from *below*, hence the minus sign.

Now for a piecewise function $f(x)$; $P(a \lt X \le b)$ is defined to be $F(b)-F(a)$

where $F(x) = P(X \le x)$

In your question $F(1)=P(X \le 1)$ not $P(X = 1)$, this is because $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution.

$X$ is the (discrete) random variable and $x$ is the value that the random variable takes.

As an example consider a regular die, in that case $X$ would be the *possible* values the random variable $X$ can take, and $x=1,2,3,4,5,6$.